# Can I set slicers visibility to false? if yes then how?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, powerbi-embedded, slicers

I need to hide report visual slicers but should not be removed.

Hidden visual slicers

Comment: Hi, can you add some of your code so we have an idea what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It's possible. Using `customLayout`, you can hide the slicer visual. You need to get the Report Name and Slicer Visual Name.

```
const settings = {
    layoutType: models.LayoutType.Custom,
    customLayout: {
   
        displayOption: models.DisplayOption.FitToPage,
        pagesLayout: {
            "ReportSectionName`": {
                visualsLayout: {
                    "SlicerVisualName": {
                        displayState: {
                            mode: models.VisualContainerDisplayMode.Hidden
                        }
                    },
                }
            }
        },
    }
```

Update the Settings either at load time by passing in `embedConfig` or at runtime by `updateSettings`  API.

References:
[CustomLayout-PowerBIEmbedded](https://learn.microsoft.com/javascript/api/overview/powerbi/custom-layout#update-the-layout)